# Transform JSON column to string

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a script that selects data into an XML table with a single column and then converts that into a string:

```
(
    SELECT N'DECLARE @' + REPLACE( COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_' ) + @CrLf
    FROM @TABLE
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value( '.', 'nvarchar(max)' ) + @CrLf +
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with JSON but I just can't seem to figure out the last part.  I'm able to create a table with a single column but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to convert to a string:

```
(
    SELECT ( N'DECLARE @' + REPLACE( COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_' ) + @CrLf ) AS MyString
    FROM @TABLE
    FOR JSON PATH
)
```

Here is a testable sample (which includes the above):

```
DECLARE @CrLf       nchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
DECLARE @TABLE      TABLE ( [COLUMN_NAME] sysname );

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
( 'COL1' ),
( 'COL2' ),
( 'COL3' ),
( 'COL4' ),
( 'COL5' );

DECLARE @Script nvarchar(max) =
(
    SELECT N'DECLARE @' + REPLACE( COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_' ) + @CrLf
    FROM @TABLE
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value( '.', 'nvarchar(max)' ) + @CrLf + 
(
    SELECT ( N'DECLARE @' + REPLACE( COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_' ) + @CrLf ) AS MyString
    FROM @TABLE
    FOR JSON PATH
);

SELECT @Script;
```

It outputs the following:

```
XML Transform:
DECLARE @COL1
DECLARE @COL2
DECLARE @COL3
DECLARE @COL4
DECLARE @COL5

JSON Transform:
[{"MyString":"DECLARE @COL1\r\n"},{"MyString":"DECLARE @COL2\r\n"},{"MyString":"DECLARE @COL3\r\n"},{"MyString":"DECLARE @COL4\r\n"},{"MyString":"DECLARE @COL5\r\n"}]
```

So in closing, I'm trying to get the JSON Transform to look the same as the XML Transform does.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
DECLARE @TABLE      TABLE ( [COLUMN_NAME] sysname );

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
( 'COL1' ),
( 'COL2' ),
( 'COL3' ),
( 'COL4' ),
( 'COL5' );

DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
(
    SELECT N'DECLARE @' + REPLACE( COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_' ) AS MyString
    FROM @TABLE
    FOR JSON PATH
)

SELECT JSON_VALUE(value,'$.MyString') AS 'JSON Transform'
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$')
```

Results

```
+--------------+
|JSON Transform|
+--------------+
| DECLARE @COL1|
| DECLARE @COL2|
| DECLARE @COL3|
| DECLARE @COL4|
| DECLARE @COL5|
+--------------+
```

This link you help you understand the `OPENJSON` and `JSON_VALUE` functions, [JSON Path Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks for this, I need it transformed to a single string inside the main statement, yours returns a table and is functionally equivalent to `SELECT N'DECLARE @' + REPLACE( COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_' ) FROM @TABLE;`.  I'm starting to think it's not possible in JSON.  Still, I appreciate your input.